# i want images fadein fadeout on imageview repeatedly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   imgView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_slide_1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_slide_1.png"]
 }
```

i want images fadein fadeout on imageview repeatedly

Comment: This is what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can't set `fadein`-`fadeout` animation on `UIImage`. Take two `UIImageView` and try to change them one bye one with animation. [Do some R&D].

Comment: looks like you are repeatedly asking the same question, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835962/i-have-many-images-in-array-i-want-fadein-fadeout-on-imageview-repeatedly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:
`[UiView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]`

And then fadeIn, FadeOut on completion change the image, ant fadeIn it again.
But if you want animation overlapping, then you should use 2 UIImageView's.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myname.png"];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
              duration:5.0f
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
            animations:^{
              self.imageView.image = toImage;
            } completion:nil];
```

Comment: ``-viewDidLoad`` is bad place for animation. You should start animation in ``-viewDidAppear``